# UiPath - Options - Add Headers within Read Range adding excel column headers while unselected and not adding column headers while selected

Tags: excel, excel-2007, uipath

New to UiPath. I am trying to read a `.xls` file and write the contents within a `.xlsx` file. It seems:

- When `Options - Add Headers` within **Read Range** is *unselected* headers are copied from `.xls` file to `.xlsx` file.
- When `Options - Add Headers` within **Read Range** is *selected* headers are **not** copied from `.xls` file to `.xlsx` file.

Snapshot of the control:

[image: AddHeaders]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Read Range` activity reads data into a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2) object. Checking AddHeaders makes sure that columns are present in said object. Here's an example - `Read Range` writes items into a variable called `items` of type `System.Data.DataTable`, and the `Write Range` activity writes that table back to an Excel (XLSX or XLS) sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@WolfgangRadl's answer is the most canonical and the accepted answer to this question.

However, as a beginner I misinterpreted the implementation of `Options - Add Headers` which can be summarized as below:

- When `Options - Add Headers` within *Read Range* is selected, *Column Headers* are identified and are not read as a part of the data to be read from the `.xls` file.
- Snapshot:

[image: Add_Headers_selected]

- When `Options - Add Headers` within *Read Range* is unselected, *Column Headers* are considered as a part of the data to be read from the `.xls` file.
- Snapshot:

[image: Add_Headers_not_selected]

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for your answer!